# Using \ to extend single-line comments

Tags: c, comments, c-preprocessor

I just noticed that I can use `\` to extend the single-line comment to the next line, similarly to doing so in pre-processor directives.

Why is nobody speaking for this language feature?
I didn't even see it in books..
What language version supports this?

Comment: Comment or a `macro`? Comment can be extended by `*` also.. /* Comment 
* __________ */

Comment: @Gopi Comment `//`

Comment: You just escape the `newline`, basically it stays a single-line comment.

Comment: i.e with `slash \ ` I can trim lines into a single line for the pre-processor/compiler?

Comment: @rkta are you sure about that?

Comment: @rkta this is talking about macros. ( Also as it is a C extension it seems not to be standard compliant) This would be relevant to comments: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Initial-processing.html but I am not sure about the standard compliance of this.

Comment: I just tested and it also works for strings. I can transfer the string in a new line without additional pair of "s, although I loose identation.

Comment: Each pair backslash & newline is deleted by the preprocessor. Citing the c11 standard, 5.1.1.2 : "Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. "

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's part of C. Called **line splicing**.

The K&R book talks about it

> Lines that end with the backslash character \ are folded by deleting the backslash and the
>   following newline character. This occurs before division into tokens.

This occurs in the preprocessing phase.

So single line comments can be made to appear like multi line like

```
//This is \
still a single line comment
```

Likewise with the case of strings

```
char str[]="Hello \
world. This is \
a string";
```

Edit: As noted in the comments, single line comments were not there in ANSI C but were introduced as part of the standard in C99 though many compilers already supported it.

[From C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.4.9p2),

> Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters // introduce a comment that includes all multibyte characters up to, but not including, the next new-line character. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the terminating new-line character.

As far as line splicing is concerned, it is specified in C89 itself

[2.1.1.2 Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#2.1.1.2)

> 2. Each instance of a new-line character and an immediately preceding backslash character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character.

Look at KamiKaze's answer to see the relevant part of C99.

Comment: I believe the single line comments weren't there when K&R was written, so I would take anything related to these to a limited extent

Comment: Single line comments were added to the standard in C99. But were available on compilers much earlier, because C++ had them.

Comment: Still I think your answer is correct as the it is talking about lines in general. So it does not care if it is a comment or a macro or just code. It is spliced no matter what. This includes unofficial single line comments. So It maybe worth to point out that it has nothing to do with comments in general, but is a language feature.

Comment: It is correct indeed. It's just the reference might be outdated in general.

Comment: @KamiKaze Eugene Yeah. The C99 standard is a better reference than K&R book as back then single line comment was not really part of the standard.

Answer (score 6):

While it's true that a `\` will effectively escape the newline at the end of a single-line comment, splicing the line with the following one (just as it does on any other line), you could claim that this is a bug in the Standard.  At any rate, the situation is fantastically confusing.  You might believe that both of these facts are true:

1. The single-line comment syntax `//` turns the rest of the line, up to the next newline, into a comment, which is not interpreted in any way, i.e. is ignored.
2. At the end of any line, a `\` character eliminates the newline and splices the line to the following line.

But these two rules are basically in conflict; it looks like they can't both be true at the same time.

Now in fact, by definition, the second rule "wins", and the first rule really has to say that the rest of the line is not interpreted in any way *except to check whether the last character is a `\`, in which case it retains its line-splicing meaning*.

(Now, if you're a compiler writer or a language lawyer, of course, you don't think about it that way.  If you're a compiler writer or language lawyer, you know that the `\` was processed during an earlier phase of compilation, before comments are parsed, meaning that the first rule is perfectly true as stated.  But most people don't think like compiler writers and language lawyers.)

My point is that this situation is basically fraught with peril.  I would bet good money that there are compilers or other language processors out there that get this wrong.  I would urge any sane programmer *not* to rely on this, not to put a `\` at the end of any line that contains a single-line comment.  (And if I were writing a compiler or other language processor, I'd try to warn about this.)

Answer (score 5):

Every instance of `\` followed by a newline is removed from the source during the first phase of parsing, before tokenisation and comment handling.

As a consequence, a single line comment can be extended to the next line of source code by escaping this newline with a `\` (or a `??/` trigraph sequence):

```
// this is a single \
line comment
```

Note how the stackoverflow code highlighter is fooled by this trick and does not colorize the end of the comment line.

This feature can be further abused to make really weird looking comments:

```
/\
/\  This is a single line comment /\
\/                                \/


/\
*\ This is a multi-line comment
*\
/
```

Any token can be broken in pieces this way. Check this *corner* case:

```
\
r\
et\
urn\
 0x7\
ffff;\
```

Comment: ahaha, we should use this in code obfuscation competitions ! That's some hideous looking return statement

Comment: Nice return statement.

Comment: @Edenia I bet they know, I bet they can do much better :D

Comment: @KamiKaze: or arguably *much worse* ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a feature of comments but a general feature of the language, as it  applies to all newline-characters.

The following is found in the [C99 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2):

> 5.1.1.2 Translation phases
>
> 2. Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.

So it is standard compliant for C99 at least.
It is not much talked about, because the relevant usecases (except for large macros and strings) are quite rare. If you need a multiline comment (the standard comment in C,  // was added from C++ later on), you could just use

```
/* multi
   line
   comment
*/
```

Every use except for large macros and strings will make the code harder to read and might even make it quite confusing. So generally it is not used except for the mentioned niches.